# JavaScript: Secondary combobox does not refresh

Tags: javascript, onchange, html-select

I want to populate a dropdown list with values that depend on another dropdown, that is, when I select an item in the first control, the second control should load the corresponding "subitems".

This is my JS code (in the HTML head):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var tipos = new Array("Tipo1", "Tipo2", "Tipo3");
var subtipos_aux = new Array();
subtipos_aux[0]="Esto no deberia aparecer";
subtipos_aux[1]="Subtipos para TIPO1|Subtipos para TIPO1";
subtipos_aux[2]="Subtipos para TIPO2|Subtipos para TIPO2";
subtipos_aux[3]="Subtipos para TIPO3|Subtipos para TIPO3|Subtipos para TIPO3";

function cargarTipos() {
    var lista = document.getElementById('__tipo');
    var x, i = 0;
    for(x in tipos){
        lista.options[i++] = new Option(tipos[x],tipos[x]);
    }
}

function cargarSubtipos(id_tipo) {
    var lista = document.getElementById('__subtipo');
    var x, i = 0; id_tipo++;
    var subtipos = subtipos_aux[id_tipo].split("|");
    for(x in subtipos) {
        lista.options[i++] = new Option(subtipos[x],subtipos[x]);
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the functions in the HTML body:

```
<fieldset>
  ...
  <select id="__tipo" name="__tipo" onchange="cargarSubtipos(this.selectedIndex);">
  ...
  <select id="__subtipo" name="__subtipo">
  ...
</fieldset>

<script language="javascript">cargarTipos("__tipo");</script>
```

The main list loads perfectly and when I select an option from it, the function that reads the subtypes IS called. However, the secondary list doesn't show anything!
I put alerts everywhere and noticed that:

1. Read value of selectedIndex: OK
2. Get appropriate element from subtipos_aux: OK
3. Conversion of subtipos_aux to subtipos (array) is OK (I put an alert inside the for loop)

So that's it, could someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not filling the select when you load it, so you need to put this at the end of  cargarTipos:

```
cargarSubtipos(0);
```

[There's an example](http://jsbin.com/iwilij/2/)